# Dynamic returned values in append function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using [d3 library](http://d3js.org/) and I want to create different elements by checking some values. If I do:

```
elements.append("rect").attr(...);
```

What happens if I want to create different elements? I tried:

```
elements.append(function (d) {
   if (d.foo) {
      return "rect";
   }
   return "circle";
});
```

This seems not to work.

What's the alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already pointed out, `.append()` accepts a function that returns the DOM element to append. This looks as follows.

```
var data = ["circle", "rect"];

d3.select("svg").selectAll(".shape").data(data)
  .enter()
  .append(function(d) {
    return document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, d);
  });
```

Of course you also need to set all the attributes correctly, which is the crux of the method -- in principle you don't need lots of `if`/`switch` statements to handle each element type, but in practice you do because the attributes you need to set differ (unless you want to set everything for everything).

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7jsxjpp/).

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm working with d3, and probably I will ask more question about d3. So, be ready. :D

Answer (score 0):

Even [`append` function accepts a function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append), I'm not sure how that should work (maybe someone brings the light here). However the following solution is human readable and easy to implement:

```
elements.each(function (d) {
   var el = d3.select(this);
   var type = "circle";
   if (el.foo) {
       type = "rect";
   }
   var aType = el.append(type);
   if (type === "rect") {
       aType.attr("rx", 5)
            .attr("ry", 5)
            .attr("height", ...)
            .attr("width", ...);
   } else if (type === "circle") {
       aType.attr("r", ...);
   }
});
```